# Flaming swords/on fire swords

Tags: first-appearance

What was the first film to use flaming/on fire swords? I'm most interested in when they're used in an offensive manner.

Comment: “But who started this crazy idea?” [The Bible?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaming_sword_%28mythology%29)

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question a bit so it is clearly limited to the first appearance in a movie. This really is not the right place to ask about books. Also asking about two different things in one question (first book/first film) is not good. In the current state its unclear what you want to know.

Comment: @atticae Yes you're right. I'll clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

So far most of the film references I've found were to more recent fare (Scott Pilgrim for example) so I'm not sure what film is the first to have fire swords. However, I believe that I can answer your first question, the one about who started this crazy idea. In Genesis 3:24 after driving the humans out, God places a Cherubim with a flaming sword on the path to Tree of Life to guard it.

Comment: So any movies covering Genesis 3:24 then.... ;)